# In memory exporter not collecting the activity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, open-telemetry

I have a test in which I am trying to collect an activity/span in memory using the In-Memory exporter. But the test fails with exception that says the collection is empty.

I have tried adding delay before assertion but result is still the same. Is anything more required in the setup so it starts capturing the activities?

```
    [Fact]
    public void Can_collect_Activities_in_memory()
    {
        var serviceName = "ServiceName";
        var activities = new List<Activity>();

        var tracerProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource(serviceName)
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("in-memory"))
            .AddInMemoryExporter(activities)
            .Build();

        var source = new ActivitySource(serviceName);

        var activity = source.StartActivity("TestActivity");

        Assert.Single(activities);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I need to stop the Activity first.